# How do I fix the problem with border when an obstacle is getting printed in snake game?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So this is my first attempt on making the snake game.The snake can move and eat food.The game works fine.Now I tried adding obstacles in the game.But when the obstacle gets printed,the right side border shifts to the right.Why is the border getting distorted?What changes do I need to make in the draw function so that the border does not shift?

```
    void draw()
    {
     system("CLS");
     for(int i=0;i<width+2;i++)
     cout<<"#";
     cout<<endl;

     for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
     {
       for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
       {
           if(j==0)
            cout<<"#";
            if(i==y && j==x)
                cout<<"O";//snake
                else if(i==fruitY && j==fruitX)
                    cout<<"@";//fruit
                    else if(i==obY && j==obY)
                        cout<<"=====";//obstacle

            else
            {
                bool print =false;
                for(int k=0;k < ntail ;k++)
                {
                  if(tailX[k]==j && tailY[k]==i)
                    {
                     cout<<"O";
                     print=true;
                    }

                }
                  if(!print)
                   cout<<" ";
            }
           if(j==width-1)
            cout<<"#";
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<width+2;i++)
      cout<<"#";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Score:"<<score<<endl;
    }
```

This is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <conio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <windows.h>    
using namespace std;
bool gameover;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score, obX, obY;
int tailX[100], tailY[100];
int ntail;
enum eDirection
{
    STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN

};
eDirection dir;

void setup()
{
    gameover = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    obX = rand() % width;
    obY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}
void draw()
{

    system("CLS");
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                cout << "#"; //printing border along height-left
            if (i == y && j == x) //snake
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                cout << "@";
            else if (i == obY && j == obY)
                cout << "=====";

            else
            {
                bool print = false;
                for (int k = 0; k < ntail; k++)
                {

                    if (tailX[k] == j && tailY[k] == i)
                    {
                        cout << "O";
                        print = true;

                    }

                }

                if (!print)
                    cout << " ";
            }

            if (j == width - 1) //printing border along height-right
                cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Score:" << score << endl;

}

void input()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
            case 'a':
                dir = LEFT;
                break;
            case 'd':
                dir = RIGHT;
                break;
            case 's':
                dir = DOWN;
                break;
            case 'w':
                dir = UP;
                break;
            case 'x':
                gameover = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
void logic()
{
    int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    tailX[0] = x;
    tailY[0] = y;
    for (int i = 1; i < ntail; i++)
    {
        prev2X = tailX[i];
        prev2Y = tailY[i];
        tailX[i] = prevX;
        tailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;
    }

    switch (dir)
    {

        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    if (x > width || x < 0 || y > height || y < 0)
        gameover = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < ntail; i++)
        if (tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y)
            gameover = true;

    if (x == fruitX && y == fruitY)
    {

        score += 10;
        fruitX = rand() % width;
        fruitY = rand() % height;
        obX = rand() % width;
        obY = rand() % height;
        ntail++;
    }

}

int main()
{
    setup();
    while (!gameover)
    {
        draw();
        input();
        logic();
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: snake]

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, format your code consistently, preferably using an automatic tool.

Comment: You're printing 5 characters for an obstacle, and 1 for everything else... what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What happens with a horizontal snake? If that draws correctly you might want to reuse that bit of code.

Comment: Just print the obstacle one character at a time like you do everything else

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
        else if (i == obY && j == obY)
            cout << "=====";
```

you print 4 more chars than in the other cases. As a result, the border gets moved by 4 chars. No surprises there.

A minimal (ugly) fix is:

```
        else if (i == obY && j == obY)
        {
            cout << "=====";
            j += 4
        }
```

It will work if there's no fruit or snake overlapping the obstacle. But if you want it cleaner, you would need to change the whole output to use a buffer (array of row strings) and only print it when done adding everything.